How to build a separate new project from an existing open-source project?
I found a good open-source project related to my need and I am somewhat contributing to it but I am starting to realize that I want to create a similar but a bit different project than the original one. That's why I am thinking of using it as the base for my entirely new project that'll deviate from the original one. So how do I do this? I mean like, do I fork it and just start making my own modifications, never sending PR to the original project (as mine will be different) or what are good practices/approaches for doing this? I might scale it to something big too. Guide me here please!
I know forking but I think I can't make forked repos private, so is it a good idea to fork the repos you want to use as base for a newer project.

If you clone the repo on your machine and then push it to your git platform (let's say github) then you should be able to make it private.
Be aware though that you're still bound by the terms of the license of the original project so keep that on mind.
